In Jetpack Compose how can I navigate from a Scaffold with bottom navigation to where I came from?
I have a Scaffold with a bottom navigation. I navigate to this Scaffold from a root NavGraph when the user log in successfully. I made a completely new NavGraph which I call in the content section of the Scaffold, and it's navigate accross the featured screens.
Is this the correct way to do this?
My another question is, if the User can log out, to the starter screen, it means from the content's NavGraph composable, somehow I have to return to the original NavGraph composable.
I have no clue how can I do that.
Can you help me decide is this the correct idea, and if yes, how can I navigate back to the original NavGraph.
